# Set the last value of a dynamic array of char pointers in C to NULL for while loop termination?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, null, malloc

I have a few questions based off the code below.

1. Would this be the correct way to have a sentinel value of NULL at the end of this dynamic array of char pointers? If not what could I do?
2. Will the code below cause a memory leak because I am setting malloced memory to NULL?

My general question would be.

1. What could I possibly do so that I can have a dynamic array of character pointers with the last value to be NULL so I can stop the loop at that point without keeping a count of how many elements in the dynamic array of character pointers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char **array_strings = NULL;
    array_strings = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    array_strings[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    strcpy(array_strings[0],"test");
    array_strings[1]=NULL;
    while (array_strings[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("array_strings[%d]: %s", i, array_strings[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(array_strings[0]);
    free(array_strings[1]);
    free(array_strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to copy strings.  The second line of `array_strings[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);` —
    `array_strings[0] = "test";` throws away the allocated memory; it is no longer safe to `free(array_strings[0])` because the string was not allocated by `malloc()`.

Comment: Just use `array_strings[1] = NULL;`  You're not copying anything - you're just setting a pointer to `NULL`.  Or you could push the limits of C and use `calloc()` to allocate your array - the zero'd memory will set the pointers to `NULL` (but only on systems where a numeric zero in the pointer is `NULL` - which is pretty much every system extant...).

Comment: `free(array_strings[1]);` is useless because you set `array_strings[1]` to `NULL`

Comment: If you're reviewing this question and the comments, be aware that the code in the question went through at least three iterations. As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312756/set-the-last-value-of-a-dynamic-array-of-char-pointers-in-c-to-null-for-while-lo#comment126052555_71312756), one problem was not using `strcpy()`; as noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312756/X#comment126052684_71312756) by [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312756/X#comment126052684_71312756), using `strcpy(array_strings[1], NULL);` was incorrect too.

Comment: No problem for setting a pointer to NULL and yes it is one of the correct ways. But free(array_strings[1]) does not affect anything because your target address to be freed is NULL. Also, you didn't allocate your last pointer, so no need to use free on it. Lastly, I don't think that wasting a pointer to mark the end of your array is a memory leak unless you deal with the N number of **array_strings array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be the correct way to have a sentinel value of NULL at the end of this dynamic array of char pointers? If not what could I do?

This is correct. You have an dynamic array of `char` pointers, with the last pointer being set to `NULL`. There is no mistake there.

> Will the code below cause a memory leak because I am setting malloced memory to NULL

You are storing `NULL` in `malloc`ed memory, not setting any reference to the memory to `NULL`, so there is no memory leak. All pointers returned by `malloc` are `free`d.